# Better to take gold or experience in Might & Magic Heroes VI?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In Might & Magic Heroes VI there are certain treasure chests that let you choose between gold and experience. To beat the game most easily which one should you choose early on?

Comment: I'm amused that the choice has changed from (in previous games) "take the gold, or distribute it to the peasants for xp" to "just keep the gold, or use it to buy rare grimoires to study". No love for the peasants, anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends.

Generally speaking, a larger army is better than a few levels on a hero, so that would indicate that it is better to take the gold.  However, as your hero gains levels, it takes more and more experience to gain a level, which makes the experience in the treasure chests worth relatively less, which indicates that you should take the experience to maximize its effectiveness.

Therefore, I usually choose gold on a small / medium map (when I know I will encounter enemy heroes in a short timeframe) and experience on larger maps (when I know I will have time to explore and build out my main town prior to encountering the enemy).

In the late game, you usually have more than enough gold and a high level hero, which is when I start leaving the treasure chests so that secondary heroes can get a few easy levels.

Comment: The campaigns in previous games also limited your hero's level. If you're already at the cap, no reason *not* to take the gold.

Comment: @Raven I haven't experienced a level cap yet, though I've only played two missions so that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

Comment: There is a level cap in the campaigns.  For instance, the Necropolis campaign caps you at level 10 in the first mission and level 15 in the second.  Also, once you are at the cap, you can only take the gold.  The experience option is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Because your hero carries over from one campaign level to the next, and because I've never been limited by gold at least so far, I've always been taking experience in the campaign.  If you need a boost of gold to accomplish some goal, then by all means take it, but I would only give up the potential experience if you're going to put the gold to an immediate use.  It takes a lot of experience to level up as you get further in the game, and one extra level up can mean a very powerful new skill.

Answer (score 2):

2000 gold or 1500 experience - I take experience. 1000 gold or 500 experience - I take gold. 1500 gold or 1000 experience - it depends but usually gold.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on situation. Early on in a map you probably want to take the gold, to level up your town faster, but if you already have enough gold to do that properly, then go for experience.

If you play the campaign, you will probably hit the exp cap if you fight most neutral monsters you can find, and if you have a big set of well developed towns chances are you wont afford all creatures.

There is no easy answer, but simplified; if you need gold take it, otherwise go for the exp.

Answer (score 0):

I never or rarely rarely take XP,XP means nothing when you're in the high levels,you could get XP anywhere by killing monsters as long as you recruit your army as strong and early as possible with your high money instead of getting XP in the boxes but owning a weak army